# How can I dump ALL Gimple trees?

Tags: gcc, internals, gimple

I need to dump all Gimple trees (kind of -fdump-tree-whatever). I created a plugin for the purpose, but I am not sure how should I access Gimple trees in pass. Plugin is hooked into GIMPLE_PASS:

```
static struct opt_pass my_pass = 
 {
    .type = GIMPLE_PASS,
    ...
```

I tried to iterate over basic blocks using gsi (gimple_stmt_iterator), however, my dump is incomplete.

Can you help me, how should I access the Gimple trees, to get every single tree dumped?

Comment: Not clear what's wrong with -fdump-tree-all

Comment: It's incomplete, ie. global variables... But that doesn't really matter. Gimple manipulation is the question

Comment: Global variables are not part of function context and can not be dumped pass-wise with any statement iterator, ever. Please specify in question what exact information do you need and how are you trying to access it with gsi.

Comment: I need everything necessary for complete reconstruction - so I could take the export and let it process with the front end.

Comment: Something like https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GimpleFrontEnd ? I think it is not possible in practice (means: too hard). Gimple just not built for it, too much inconsistence, too much inconvenience.

Comment: yes, this is pretty much what I am working on. 
Do you think, it would be easier using GENERIC?

Answer (score 3):

The most useful option is -fdump-tree-gimple

Answer (score 2):

Use `-fdump-tree-all` to dump all passes for `tree`.